# @ethersproject/contracts no such method .send(), how do i initiate from

Tags: web3js, dapps

a.ts - useContract

```
import { Contract } from "@ethersproject/contracts";
return new Contract(address, ABI, library.getSigner(account))
```

b.ts myContract

```
import { useContract } from "a.ts";
return useContract<ERC20>(address, abi);
```

c.ts

```
import { myContract } from "a.ts";
const abcContract = myContract()
abcContract.approve(addrss,1) // can work
abcContract.approve(addrss,1).send({ from: myaccount }); //no such method
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.